# Django model importing issue

Tags: python, django, database

I'm new to Django.
I've been trying to import my model.py into a custom management command file, but it tells me:

```
Unable to import 'Educationa_Organization_Management_System.Subjects.models
```

and when I tried to remove the folder name from the import, I still got this error message:

```
Unable to import 'Subjects.models
```

Here's my code in the **custom command file** :

```
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand
from Educationa_Organization_Management_System.Subjects.models import Subject


class Command(BaseCommand):
    def add_arguments(self, parser):
        parser.add_argument("Subject_name")
        parser.add_argument("Instructor_name")
        parser.add_argument("prerequisites", action="store_true")
        parser.add_argument("Assistant_name")
        parser.add_argument("Course_description")
        parser.add_argument("Validation_date")
        parser.add_argument("SubjectNumberOfChapters")
        parser.add_argument("numberOfLecturesPerWeek")
        parser.add_argument("numberOfSectionsPerWeek")
        parser.add_argument("Subject_FullGrade")

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        subject = Subject(
            name=options['name'],
            Instructor_name=options['Instructor_name'],
            prerequisites=options['prerequisites'],
            Assistant_name=options['Assistant_name'],
            Course_description=options['Course_description'],
            Validation_date=options['Validation_date'],
            SubjectNumberOfChapters=options['SubjectNumberOfChapters'],
            numberOfLecturesPerWeek=options['numberOfLecturesPerWeek'],
            numberOfSectionsPerWeek=options['numberOfSectionsPerWeek'],
            Subject_FullGrade=options['Subject_FullGrade'],
        )
        subject.save()
        self.stdout.write(self.style.SUCCESS(
            "Subject has been successfully added to the database"))
```

and here's my **model.py** file content:

```
from django.db import models


class Subject(models.Model):
    Subject_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False)
    Instructor_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False)
    prerequisites = models.BooleanField()
    Assistant_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False)
    Course_description = models.TextField()
    Validation_date = models.DateTimeField()
    SubjectNumberOfChapters = models.IntegerField(blank=False, null=False)
    numberOfLecturesPerWeek = models.IntegerField()
    numberOfSectionsPerWeek = models.IntegerField()
    Subject_FullGrade = models.IntegerField()
```

And finally, Here're my folders:

[image]

Yeah, also, the app is in the setting.py file in the `INSTALLED_APPS` part.

Comment: try `from Subjects.models import Subject`

Comment: How are you executing the custom command? As `python3 manage.py customcommand`?

Comment: @JPG I tried it and it gave the same error as you can see in the second error dialog

Comment: @00 yep, that's how I do it

Comment: Just to note, you should start using snake case when declaring module/file/variable names in Python, eg. `subject_name` instead of `Subject_name`, `educationa_organization_management_system` instead of `Educationa_Organization_Management_System` etc. https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions

Answer (score 0):

Well, after a long 2-day search, I found that the issue was that inside the command folder I didn't have the `__init__.py` file.

When I added it, everything worked perfectly.

Here's the final directory tree:

```
|   db.sqlite3
|   manage.py
|   Subjects.xlsx
|   
+---Educationa_Organization_Management_System
|   |   asgi.py
|   |   settings.py
|   |   urls.py
|   |   wsgi.py
|   |   __init__.py
|   |   
|   \---__pycache__
|           settings.cpython-39.pyc
|           urls.cpython-39.pyc
|           wsgi.cpython-39.pyc
|           __init__.cpython-39.pyc
|           
\---Subjects
    |   admin.py
    |   apps.py
    |   models.py
    |   Subjects.csv
    |   tests.py
    |   views.py
    |   __init__.py
    |   
    +---management
    |   |   __init__.py
    |   |   
    |   +---commands
    |   |   |   Student_database_Upload.py
    |   |   |   __init__.py
    |   |   |   
    |   |   \---__pycache__
    |   |           Database_migration.cpython-39.pyc
    |   |           __init__.cpython-39.pyc
    |   |           
    |   \---__pycache__
    |           __init__.cpython-39.pyc
    |           
    +---migrations
    |   |   0001_initial.py
    |   |   0002_auto_20210125_2052.py
    |   |   0003_auto_20210125_2255.py
    |   |   0004_auto_20210126_1944.py
    |   |   0005_auto_20210126_1946.py
    |   |   __init__.py
    |   |   
    |   \---__pycache__
    |           0001_initial.cpython-39.pyc
    |           0002_auto_20210125_2052.cpython-39.pyc
    |           0003_auto_20210125_2255.cpython-39.pyc
    |           0004_auto_20210126_1944.cpython-39.pyc
    |           0005_auto_20210126_1946.cpython-39.pyc
    |           __init__.cpython-39.pyc
    |           
    \---__pycache__
            admin.cpython-39.pyc
            models.cpython-39.pyc
            __init__.cpython-39.pyc
```